# Drawing from one Form on another while the one is closing/closed

Tags: c#, winforms, drawing, multiple-forms

I am programming something in c# for school. I have 2 Forms and while I close the child form I want to draw something on the parent Form and I don't want to use any button I would have to click afterwards. This is what I have tried but it doesn't work.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {    
      this.Close(); //Closes Form2(Child)
    }
private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        Graphics g;
        g = f1.CreateGraphics();
        g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 100, 100, 50, 50);
    }
```

I also have tried using the FormClosed event.

Comment: I deleted my post. Well I wanted to select the first Form(parent) to create a graphic on it, the first Form doesn't do anything else than opening the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your parent form, when you initialize the child form, set it's `Owner` property to `this`:

```
var form2 = new Form2();
form2.Owner = this;
```

And then from the child form, you can access the parent by doing this:

```
Graphics g;
g = ((Form1)this.Owner).CreateGraphics();
g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 100, 100, 50, 50);
```

Comment: Glad to help. Just to make sure you understand why it works now - in your code, you were creating a NEW Form1 (`var f1 = new Form1()`) which is a completely different instance of that form than the one you used to open `Form2`. In order to manipulate data on the original form, you need to access that instance, not another one.

Comment: Yea, sorry I am kind of new to programming but I understand what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Taking in consideration your Form1 is the parent form and Form2 is your child form, that is Form2 is being called from Form1 originally. Then you should first send your copy of Form1 to the new Form2 you are creating, stored it on a private field and on closing use it to draw on it. Something similar to:

```
private Form1 _parent;
public Form2(Form1 parent)
{
  _parent = parent;
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
  this.Close(); //Closes Form2(Child)
}
private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = _parent.CreateGraphics();
    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 100, 100, 50, 50);
}
```

Also on parent, you should have something similar to:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
  Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
  form2.Show();
}
```

The problem with the code you posted is that you are creating a new Form1, which is not the same **object/instance** as the original Form1 you have already when opening a new instance Form2.

Comment: While this will work, you can just use the form's `Owner` property.

Comment: Strictly speaking `Owner` property adds more behavior to Form2 than the one asked on this question. That’s why I decided not to use it.